# Why is one instance's CPU at 100% on my ElasticBeanstalk Environnent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ElasticBeanstalk environment setup which scales up to 6 instances. All of the 6 instances are more or less receiving the same request, but regardless of the number of requests received one instance says it's using 100% of the CPU.

[image]

I've tried terminating the instance and it just adds another instance and then a different instance takes its place at the bottom stating that it's using 100% of the CPU.

It doesn't seem to be returning errors either.

The instances are all t4g.large spot instances.

These instances are Python Servers running the FastAPI Framework. They are handling thousands of GET requests, from a Job server. All the GET requests are the same, they just contain different META data.

Comment: What type of instances do you have?

Comment: They are all t4g.large spot instances.

Comment: Since they are burstable instances, did you checked the available CPU credits? Maybe that instance is just the first that have consumed all the credits.

Comment: It happened immediately after I kicked off the process that is making requests to the servers and when I terminated the instance that was showing 100% CPU in use another instance immediately took it's place stating it was using 100% of the CPU. The process is still running and none of the other instances are showing more then a few percentage of CPU use.

Comment: What "process that is making requests to the servers"? You made no mention of this in your question.

Comment: Updated the question. These instances are Python FastAPI web servers which are all handling the same GET request with different meta data.